# View progress of a package installation in terminal

Tags: package-management

When I am using the Ubuntu Software Updater to install or upgrade packages, I can see a progress bar that shows how much of the installation is complete. When I am using the command line `apt-get` tool, there is no such progress indicator. Is there a way to easily see the progress of a package installation when using a command line application such as `apt-get`?

Comment: The longest part of an install is downloading the package. [`apt-fast`](https://launchpad.net/~apt-fast/+archive/stable) provides more detail in this respect. "apt-fast is a shellscript wrapper for apt-get and aptitude that can drastically improve APT download times by downloading packages with multiple connections per package."

Comment: Thanks, vasa1. However, I am looking for something that will allow me to see the progress of the unpacking and installation of packages, not just the downloading.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use debconf-apt-progress, which should be included in ubuntu by default.
Basic syntax:

```
sudo apt-get install <package> | debconf-apt-progress
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry but as far as I'm aware there isn't.

The best you can do is estimate it yourself, from the number of packages, and the number of "Unpacking" and "Setting up" messages you've seen.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like apt just recently added a progress bar, which isn't enabled by default. See this for details; http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/how-to-enable-apt-terminal-progress-bar